# How to get min time from datetime in sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to write below code in in SQL server 2008 r2

```
DECLARE @date date
DECLARE @datetime datetime

SELECT @datetime = GETDATE()
select @date = GETDATE()

select format(cast(min(@date + @datetime) as datetime), 'hh:mm:ss tt')
```

this piece of code doesn't work in SQL Server 2008 r

Comment: What is supposed to do that code? And where do "work" that code before try in sql2008?  you assign the same value to both variables so don't understand what you want.

Comment: It looks like they think the `datetime` datatype just holds `time` values, which is why they are concatenating it to a `date` value.

Comment: Yes, i have work on sql server 2012 in local system but i tried to upload on  there are user sql server 2008 that's piece of code get error LIke

Comment: So work ok in 2012 but not in 2008? What mean doesn't work? any errors? wrong result? Again what result you expect from this query?

Comment: Yes, I get the error: 'format' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: That's because [`FORMAT()` was introduced in SQL Server 2012](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql).

Comment: Thank for the support, I got the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is confusing. You are trying to add two dates which doesn't make sense. Anyway, here's how to convert a `datetime` to output the hh:mm:ss format.

```
DECLARE @datetime datetime
SELECT @datetime = GETDATE()

select 
   DT = convert(char(10),@datetime,120)
   ,TimeOnly = left(cast(@datetime as time),8)
```